# Can I create multiple canvas elements on same page using p5js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I tried using p5js to draw some points it does work well but I also wanted another canvas element which can show the live video from camera. When I added another canvas element the first canvas goes blank. For now I tried using multiple javascript files to process different canvas.

camera.js

```
var capture;

function setup() {
  var video=createCanvas(390, 240);
  capture = createCapture(VIDEO);
  capture.size(320, 240);
  capture.hide();
  //set parent to div with id left
  video.parent("left");
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  image(capture, 0, 0, 320, 240);
  filter('INVERT');
}
```

drawshapes.js

```
function setup() {
  // Create the canvas
  var plot=createCanvas(720, 400);
  background(200);
  //set parent to div with id right
  plot.parent("right");
  // Set colors
  fill(204, 101, 192, 127);
  stroke(127, 63, 120);

  // A rectangle
  rect(40, 120, 120, 40);
  // An ellipse
  ellipse(240, 240, 80, 80);
  // A triangle
  triangle(300, 100, 320, 100, 310, 80);

  // A design for a simple flower
  translate(580, 200);
  noStroke();
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
    ellipse(0, 30, 20, 80);
    rotate(PI/5);
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 22):

You would want to use [instance mode](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Instantiation-Cases). The first few examples use **Global Mode** and the next few examples use **Instance Mode**. Instead of using the default canvas, in instance mode you control where p5js puts the canvas element. If you have two containers, you would use:

`new p5(leftSketch, 'left');
new p5(rightSketch, 'right');`

`leftSketch` and `rightSketch` would be functions that take a variable p. That variable is an instance of p5js and you can control each canvas element separately.

Comment: Instance Mode was exactly what we needed to create several interactive canvases. One thing that we found out was that we had to account for mouseX and mouseY values being outside of the draw method's canvas.  

 `if (p.mouseX > 0 && p.mouseX < p.width && p.mouseY > 0 && p.mouseY < p.height) {
 //can use mouse position
}`

Comment: I think the link is now https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode 
At least it seems broken to me.

Answer (score 14):

This is mentioned briefly on the official [p5js reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createCanvas).

> Calling createCanvas more than once in a sketch will result in very
>   unpredicable behavior. If you want more than one drawing canvas you
>   could use createGraphics (hidden by default but it can be shown).

### The solution

This admittedly isn't a *great* solution but it definitely works.

1. Create **1 canvas** for both "canvases".
2. Create **2 off-screen buffers** that you can draw to.
3. In your `draw()` function, draw whatever you want on each buffer.
4. Then copy the contents of **both buffers** onto the main canvas using `image()`.

### Example

```
var leftBuffer;
var rightBuffer;

function setup() {
    // 800 x 400 (double width to make room for each "sub-canvas")
    createCanvas(800, 400);
    // Create both of your off-screen graphics buffers
    leftBuffer = createGraphics(400, 400);
    rightBuffer = createGraphics(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
    // Draw on your buffers however you like
    drawLeftBuffer();
    drawRightBuffer();
    // Paint the off-screen buffers onto the main canvas
    image(leftBuffer, 0, 0);
    image(rightBuffer, 400, 0);
}

function drawLeftBuffer() {
    leftBuffer.background(0, 0, 0);
    leftBuffer.fill(255, 255, 255);
    leftBuffer.textSize(32);
    leftBuffer.text("This is the left buffer!", 50, 50);
}

function drawRightBuffer() {
    rightBuffer.background(255, 100, 255);
    rightBuffer.fill(0, 0, 0);
    rightBuffer.textSize(32);
    rightBuffer.text("This is the right buffer!", 50, 50);
}
```

### The result:

[image: Here is an image showing the result of the code]

Comment: I think this is the right way to go about it. Multiple canvas's will spawn multiple copies of the DOM objects.

Comment: i'm trying to translate this in es6 but still got some problems https://gist.github.com/wanbinkimoon/0771fea9b199ce5ac32edc8f6d815584

Comment: @NicolaBertelloni I responded on github.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by moving my canvases into separate html pages, and then displaying with iframes.

Example setup of a canvas html page:

```html
<style>
  /* remove whitespace and overflow that may affect the display in iframe */
  body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
</style>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.9.0/lib/p5.js"></script>

<script>
  function preload() {
    // ... some code ...
  }

  function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  }

  function draw() {
    // ... some code ...
  }
</script>
```

The actual web page:

```html
<style>
  /* remove the default styling from the iframe */
  iframe {
    border: none;
  }
</style>

<!--
    Display the canvases using iframe.
    Style and layout them out as you wish using html and css
-->
<iframe src="/canvas_examples/example_1" title="Canvas Example 1"></iframe>
<iframe src="/canvas_examples/example_2" title="Canvas Example 2"></iframe>
<iframe src="/canvas_examples/example_3" title="Canvas Example 3"></iframe>
```