# How to specify where to put a P5.js canvas in an HTML website

Tags: html, canvas, p5.js

I want to specify where my P5.js canvas will show up.

It keeps showing up at the end of the HTML document even when I change the place of the  tag. Also when I try multiple files, it only shows the first one.

Here's an example:

```
<p> text1 </p>
<script src="sketch1.js"></script> <!-- I want this canvas to be here -->
<p> text2 </p> 
<script src="sketch2.js"></script> <!-- I want this canvas to be here -->
```

The website only shows the first canvas at the end of the document.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I create multiple canvas elements on same page using p5js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240287/can-i-create-multiple-canvas-elements-on-same-page-using-p5js)

Comment: See also [How to put p5.js canvas in a html div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660240/how-to-put-p5-js-canvas-in-a-html-div). You can make two instances with instance mode and attach them to whichever divs you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up parent containers for your two canvas instances:

```
<p> text1 </p> 
<div id='myContainer1'></div>

<p> text2 </p> 
<div id='myContainer2'></div>
```

Then use:

```
// sketch1.js
function setup() {
  let myCanvas1 = createCanvas(600, 400);
  myCanvas1.parent('myContainer1');
}

// sketch2.js
function setup() {
  let myCanvas2 = createCanvas(600, 400);
  myCanvas2.parent('myContainer2');
}
```

Comment: I have my sketches in different files. What do I do for that?

Comment: Modify each file to target a separate container

Comment: I did that and I can now choose where my canvas is but it only shows the canvas from the script tag I write first.

Answer (score 0):

Nest your script tags inside a div and then style it as needed

```html
<div>
<script src="sketch1.js"></script>
</div>
```