How do I put a p5play script inside of my HTML webpage?
I have made a webpage for school and our teacher wants us to go out and learn how to do something new to add to it. I had this idea to take one of my p5play games and put it in to the website somehow, but I have zero clue where to start.
Im using codeHS to do this and I have tried making a file for the javaScript but it just prints out all of the code instead of the code actually doing anything

Have you read existing entries in StackOverflow for "embedding p5.play in a webpage"?  For example:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/37240287/20901722
